# Search support for Google App Engine Go runtime

Tags: google-app-engine, go

There is search support (experimental) for python and Java, and eventually Go also may supported. Till then, how can I do minimal search on my records?

Through the mailing list, I got an idea about proxying the search request to a python backend. I am still evaluating GAE, and not used backends yet. To setup the search with a python backed, do I have to send all the request (from Go) to data store through this backend? How practical is it, and disadvantages? Any tutorial on this.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is full text search coming for the Go runtime very very very soon.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I have seen the activity in issue list and excited to try it out. Thanks for prioritizing it.

Comment: The latest release introduced the appengine/search package. Go nuts.

Answer (score 3):

You could make a RESTful Python app that with a few handlers and your Go app would make urlfetches to the Python app. Then you can run the Python app as either a backend or a frontend (with a different version than your Go app). The first handler would receive a key as input, would fetch that entity from the datastore, and then would store the relevant info in the search index. The second handler would receive a query, do a search against the index, and return the results. You would need a handler for removing documents from the search index and any other operations you want.

Instead of the first handler receiving a key and fetching from the datastore you could also just send it the entity data in the fetch.

You could also use a service like IndexDen for now (especially if you don't have many entities to index):
http://indexden.com/

When making urlfetches keep in mind the quotas currently apply even when requesting URLs from your own app. There are two issues in the tracker requesting to have these quotas removed/increased when communicating with your own apps but there is no guarantee that will happen. See here:

- http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8051
- http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8052